# How should I control multithreaded access to several queues in the following situation?

Tags: c++, posix, mutex, semaphore, condition-variable

I'm working on a multithreaded project in C++ that sends data to a series of network connections.  Here's some pseudocode that illustrates what's going on:

```
class NetworkManager
{
    Thread    writer;      // responsible for writing data in queues to the network
    Queue[]   outqueue;    // holds data until the network is ready to receive it
    Network[] nets;        // sockets or whatever
    Mutex[]   outlock;     // protects access to members of outqueue
    Mutex     managerlock; // protects access to all queues
    Condition notifier;    // blocks the write thread when there is no data
}
```

In reality it's a whole lot more complicated than that, but I've axed a lot of unnecessary details.  One important detail is that the networking is rate-limited, and the ability of the program to queue data independently from sending it is a feature of the design (the program should not have to wait to process new data because it's blocking on a network write).

Here's a brief description of how the program is expected to interact with this class.  Note that `QueueWriteToNetwork` and `DoAdministrativeStuff` are, in my implementation, managed by THE SAME external thread.

```
QueueWriteToNetwork(network, data) // responsibility of external thread
    Let i = the index of the network to send to
    Lock(outlock[i])
    outqueue[i].Add(data)
    Unlock(outlock[i])
    Signal(notifier)

DoAdministrativeStuff(network, more) // responsibility of external thread
    Lock(managerlock)
    more.Process() // might do any of the following:
                   // connect or disconnect networks
                   // add or remove networks from list
                   // immediate write data to network, bypassing rate limiting
                   // other things that I forgot
    Unlock(managerlock)

WriterThreadMain() // responsibility of internal write thread
    Lock(managerlock)
    Loop forever:
        Check for data in every queue (locking and unlocking each queue)
        If all queues have no data to write:
            Wait(notifier, managerlock)
            continue
        If outqueue[i] has data ready to write
            Lock(outlock[i])
            Send data from outqueue[i]
            outqueue[i].Pop()
            Unlock(outqueue[i])
```

As you might be able to see, there are a few issues with this approach (for example, if a write is queued to the network with `QueueWriteToNetwork` as `WriterThreadMain` is checking if the queues are empty, the call to `Signal(notifier)` could potentially be dropped, and the write queue could remain waiting even though there was data ready).

I need to phrase this in such a way that the following are possible:

- Adding data to a write queue does not block, or blocks for only a reasonably short time (specifically, it does not block for the duration of a network write that's in progress)
- The `DoAdministrativeStuff` function must have the ability to ensure that the writer thread is blocked in a safe state (i.e. not accessing any queue, queue lock, or network)

I've explored the possibility of using a semaphore to track the number of items in write queues.  This would solve the lost-update problem I mentioned earlier.

Finally, I'm targeting Linux (using Posix libraries to provide the types `pthread_t`, `pthread_mutex_t`, `pthread_cond_t`, and `sem_t`), and I don't care about compatibility with Windows.  Also, please don't recommend Boost.  Pulling any Boost header into my code makes compilation take unbearably long.

Comment: If you do not like to compile boost then do not compile boost, just take boost::asio as example of code where all that you describe here is already implemented.

Comment: You can use the Asio library [without using boost](http://think-async.com/Asio/AsioAndBoostAsio).